# Clear list items and reset id back to 1

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list

I have a site in SharePoint production. it contains 100 lists , each list  contains test data 100- 1000 items, I am gonna to go life  and I want to clear the test data but I want to reset  all lists ID to start from 1 as a fresh list!

I can clear the list items but the ID is not reset to 1!

Please help me to find any solution for this issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Unfortunately**, you can't `truncate` the SharePoint list as you do in the Database Table!

Also, I don't think it's a practical solution to

- Delete the 100 lists then recreate it again or
- Save 100 lists as a template without content then delete the original list then recreate it again!!!

In your scenario, from the beginning, it was supposed to create a SharePoint solution/add-in for all lists definition. Once you have finished the testing phase, just redeploy your solution.

**To create A-list Definition**

- [List definition / list template in the SharePoint add-in model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/list-definition-template-sharepoint-add-in)
- [How to: Create a Custom List Definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms466023(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Most of these answers are good/relevant but this highlights the main issue: SharePoint makes it very easy to morph your dev/test solution to the production solution but this is, in general, Bad Practice because you'll pick up all the baggage of list definition changes and ideas that you may have pursued that didn't pan out, and these will ultimately change how some of your lists wind up in the final solution

Answer (score 10):

The only way to reset the ID to start from 1 again is to delete the list and then recreate it.

Answer (score 8):

One way to reset ID in a SharePoint list is that you can save list as template and then use this template to create the list again. The ID will be reset and start from 1.